# Regex with optional prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not really confortable with regexes but need to extend a legacy one.
Currently we are having this regex in our application:

```
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:\[(.*?)\])?/g;
```

This allows us to split strings like this:

```
hello[foo='bar']
```

Into:

```
hello and [foo='bar']
```

But due to a recent update, the 'hello'-part can also contain a prefix named 'abc.'. The result would be abc.hello[foo='bar']. However this is optional.

With the current regex we are having this will split into an array that only contains ['abc', 'abc', undefined]

If someone could help me add this optional prefix to the current regex that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what can be the prefix ?

Comment: Your original regex doesn't do what you say it does. i.e. split `hello[foo='bar']` to `hello and [foo='bar']`

Comment: `/(abc\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:\[(.*?)\])?/g;`

Comment: Try `(abc\.)?(\w+)(?:\[[^\]]*\])?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply prepend `(abc\.)?` to your regex, but I'd also make a slight adjustment as defined below:

```
(abc\.)?(\w+)(\[[^\]]*\])?
```

- `(abc\.)?` Optionally captures `abc.` into capture group 1
- `(\w+)` Captures one or more word characters into capture group 2. `\w` is shothand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `(?:\[[^\]]*\])?` Optionally capture the following into capture group 3

  - `\[` Matches `[` literally
  - `[^\]]*` Matches any character except `]` any number of times. This is better than using `.*?` since it doesn't backtrack. This means better performance.
  - `\]` Matches `]` literally

```js
var a = ["abc.hello[foo='bar']", "hello[foo='bar']"]
var r = /(abc\.)?(\w+)(\[[^\]]*\])?/

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s.match(r))
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and also explaining how it works in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Should work by just adding the dot to the first group in your regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)(?:\[(.*?)\])?
```

That would split

```
abc.hello[foo='bar']
```

into

```
abc.hello
```

and

```
foo='bar'
```

and also

```
hello[foo='bar']
```

into

```
hello
```

and

```
foo='bar'
```